# Main page teaser with module paragraphs?

Tags: nodes

The [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module is the only module I know which would enable me to create flexible content with floating inline images without using a WYSIWYG editor. I use the beta4 paragraphs version in connection with the Garland theme.

I was able to setup certain paragraph bundles and also a content type where it is possible to add up paragraphs to different type (e.g. text only, text with image etc.)
See example below: [image: Screenshot of comm-press.de article with inline images]

However, I failed totally to configure a teaser view which makes sense. The reason: I cannot control the number of paragraph bundles to be shown in the teaser view as ist can be seen here:

[image: Screenshot of comm-press.de article in teaser view]

In my test site the number fields next to the Fomat field in the above picture is missing. So I can only show the total article or nothing as teaser. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Drupal Answers! Well written question, +1. :) It's generally considered bad form to link to external sites, as the content of those links may change or disappear. I'm guessing you can't inline images though, as your reputation isn't high enough yet, so I took the liberty of doing so. Let me know if I got the screenshots wrong, and we can try to correct them. :)

Comment: @Letharion: Thanks for your kind answer. Unfortunately the paragraphs link has been broken: It is https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs

Comment: Ops. Fixed the url.

Comment: The essential screenshot ist this: http://comm-press.de/sites/default/files/articles/images/20140222/display-suite-article.png It shows the essential input box right to the "paragraph items" pull-down format box which contains "1". This box won't show up on my site.

Comment: After posting (somewhat desperately) this question and having a relaxing break I had the idea that there is a workaround: One can configure a content type with 2 paragraph fields: the first to be propagated also as teaser and the second to be used for the further (multiple and flexible) content. For composing the single “teaser paragraph” a field like “text_with_summary” is still of no use since only the full content may be placed on the main page as teaser. Therefore, my original question still remains open.

Answer (score 2):

The “manage display” teaser configuration page did not show the number of paragraphs to be displayed in the teaser view since the ["Display Suite" module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) was not installed. I missed the display suite module because it was not mentioned in the cited article about paragraphs. :-(

It is, however, easily possible to also generate reasonable teaser views without having the Display Suite module installed: Just configure a content type with 2 fields for the page content: The first serves as single teaser/introduction field and the second serves as vehicle to choose among multiple and per CSS differently formatted paragraphs for the following content. The first field I call “intro field” in the following.

For the intro field (to me) there seem to be certain restrictions: If one wants to use a *flexible* paragraph item for this purpose, it seems to be only possible to show or hide the element on the teaser or full content page, respectively. (Within this respect, text_with_summary appears to make no sense as element of a paragraph bundle).

On the other hand, one could also use an *unwrapped* text_with_summary field as the first part of an article. This enables the full teaser functionality where one can select from mere shortening or providing an alternative abstract. Most important the manage display page will now let you choose “summary or trimmed” as teaser.